# Safe to recycle bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a bitmap and I am creating a `byte array` from it like following

```
BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o2.inSampleSize = scale;

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri,o2);
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
b.recycle(); //safe to do here?
```

Is it safe to recycle the bitmap at this point or do I have to wait until I create the type array to recycle.

```
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
b.recycle(); //or do I need to do it here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call b.compress(), the data for the bitmap should already be written to the OutputStream, so you don't need the Bitmap any longer and it is safe to recycle it after your call to compress.

Comment: It looks like @tyczj is using a ByteArrayOutputStream in which this would be the case but are you sure this is true of all implementations of OutputStream? I don't think it is.

Comment: From the android site, here is a description of the compress method: "Write a compressed version of the bitmap to the specified outputstream." To me this seems like the compressed version of the bitmap is written after the compress function returns so there should no longer be any use for the actual Bitmap right? Since now he is using the compressed version of the bitmap from the OutputStream. How is the bitmap connected with the compressed version that was written to the outputstream?